# Simple 200px <div> wrong screen dimensions

Tags: html, css, chromium, measurement

**EDIT**
**The question has nothing to do with `box model`, `CSS` `border`, `padding`, `margin` or whatsoever**

**The question is about `CSS` `pixel` size as seen on actual screen**

**The commenters to this question have pointed me to right direction. To sum it up: None of `CSS` measurement units does correspond to actual size of physical screen**

I've asked a similar question not so long ago. The question consisted of two parts. The person who answered the question did it for the first part of the question. Now I am asking the part that troubles me most.

I made a simple `html` page

```html
 <html>
<head>
<style>
 #box_200px {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="box_200px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of the snippet should show 200px wide box. And here is my measurements with `gimp`.

[image: screen 1]

[image]

Having opened it in gimp and measured with the `gimp` measure till I got that the actual box width is `262px`.

What am I doing wrong? How to layout `<div>` as actual `200px`?

My system is the Linux Mint OS. My browser is Chromium.

Comment: Are you aware of the Box Model in CSS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Comment: A px unit isn't an actual pixel on the screen. It is 1/96 of an inch. [See this answer in our oother SE site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/12644/91687)

Comment: The pixel size differ for different sizes. https://superuser.com/questions/1103934/does-1-pixel-have-a-standard-size

Comment: @JordiNebot I saw some pictures ;)

Comment: Let me check that. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: That's not true, @MartijnVissers. A `px` unit IS actually a pixel on the screen (Obviously, its _real_ size will be different in two separate screens with different resolutions).

Comment: @JordiNebot I think that the link that `MartijnVissers` had provided tells us full story. From [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#x39) web site: **For lower-resolution devices, and devices with unusual viewing distances, it is recommended instead that the anchor unit be the pixel unit. For such devices it is recommended that the pixel unit refer to the whole number of device pixels that best approximates the reference pixel**.    ... **Note that if the anchor unit is the pixel unit, the physical units might not match their physical measurements.**

Comment: And `reference pixel` is some magic constant that do not equals to `hardware pixel`. I stick using `vmin` and `em` units for now and foreseeable future.